# Trigger code is written in

Tags: sql, database

Trigger code is written in:

1. SQL
2. PL/SQL
3. JAVA
4. Machine Language

I think options of this question is wrong, bcoz option 1 and 2 are correct. I know only one thing is that we use SQL in terms of MS SQL,MY SQL, Sybase whereas PL/SQL uses in Oracle. please correct me with exact opinion about this question?

Comment: I think it very much depends on whether this is meant to be a product specific question/test (in which case, what product?) or ANSI standard.

Comment: Please give me correct answer with proof.

Comment: is there anyone who can give answer of my question ?

Comment: It's difficult for anyone to answer the question when we don't know the **context** in which it was asked. Was it a product-specific test? Or meant to be ANSI Standard? Multi-choice or Single-choice (some of your question seems to suggest you don't believe multiple correct answers are allowed but you ought to clarify that)

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify each option:

1) Structured Query Language - used for communication with databases, and CRUD operations. Triggers are not written in SQL.

2) PL/SQL - language which used in Oracle databases, procedural language which is extension of SQL. PL/SQL has exact block structure which called trigger, which is implicitly started when an `INSERT, UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement is issued against an associated table.

3) Java is object oriented, cross-platforming high-level language. You can create some trigger-like stuff in Java, but in general it doesn't have trigger units.

4) Machine language is instructions which are executed directly on CPU for solving specific task.

So, option 2 is exactly matches the answer.